# Ignore symbol except its first existence as a first?

Tags: regex

how could I do something like that:

Input:

> +93120nvsenr++   +++:LKK213ll

Output:

> selected all non digits and all "+" except "+" which is first and start the string

Example:

> +312313__3fffa```+++31+3

Final result after `String.replaceAll(regex, "")` should be `+3123133313`

So far my regex is:

```
[^\\d^+]
```

which is: ignore all non digits and all "+" signs and gives me:

> +3123133+++31+3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
(?!^\+)\D+
    ^
    |
    |->this would replace a non digit character only if it doesn't have a +( which is at the beginning of the string) that preceed's it
```

[try it here](http://regexhero.net/tester/)